# How to pause setInterval with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a play and a pause button:

```
<div *ngIf="!playToggle">
    <button (click)="playTimeLine(); playToggle = true">
        <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="playToggle">
    <button (click)="pauseTimeLine(); playToggle = false">
        <i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

If the play button is clicked it calls the `playTimeLine` function:

```
currentTime = 0;

playTimeLine(value) {

    setInterval(() => {
        this.currentTime = this.currentTime + 10;
        console.log(this.currentTime);
    }, 1000);
}
```

I would like to add a pause function that pauses the interval. But it also makes it possible to resume it from the point it was paused.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you want to pause adding time to your currentTime, and not actually pause the interval:

Add an attribute to your class declaring the interval:

```
interval;
```

Store the interval in the attribute in your play function:

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.currentTime = this.currentTime + 10;
    console.log(this.currentTime);
}, 1000);
```

In a pause function, clear the interval:

```
pauseTimeLine(value) {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

EDIT: Note that this is not very precise timing, but depending on the purpose of your code it could be workable.

Comment: It's only for a POC so it needs to be implemented quick and refined later. This seems to do the trick :). I don't completely understand how it works though. What happens when I do this.interval = setInterval? What value is set on this.interval?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma `setInterval` returns an id reference to the interval, of which I believe the sole purpose is to pass it to `clearInterval` for... well, clearing the interval.

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible since setInterval neither allows you to pause, nor even allows you to fetch the time elapsed/remaining in the interval. You can simply create and clear intervals.

If you wanted to stop the interval, you could do the following:

```
timer = null;

startTimer() {
  this.stopTimer();
  this.timer = setInterval(() => { /* do something */ }, 1000);
}

stopTimer() {
  if (this.timer) {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
}
```

If you wish to implement a pausable timer, you will need to create your own class and use it.

Also consider using RxJS timers instead of setInterval for the implementation of your timer.

Answer (score 0):

here's example in plunker [https://plnkr.co/edit/SEh8lBCfl8L9rwHqyWJb?p=preview][1]

```
[1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/SEh8lBCfl8L9rwHqyWJb?p=preview
```

you can set variable for interval.